# Binary instance for an existential

Tags: haskell

Given an existential data type, for example:

```
data Foo = forall a . (Typeable a, Binary a) => Foo a
```

I'd like to write `instance Binary Foo`. I can write the serialisation (serialise the `TypeRep` then serialise the value), but I can't figure out how to write the deserialisation. The basic problem is that given a `TypeRep` you need to map back to the type dictionary for that type - and I don't know if that can be done.

This question has been asked before on the haskell mailing list http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2006-September/018522.html, but no answers were given.

Comment: As far as I know it can't be done in any nice way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved in GHC 7.10 and onwards using the Static Pointers Language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StaticPointers #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

data Foo = forall a . (StaticFoo a, Binary a, Show a) => Foo a

class StaticFoo a where
    staticFoo :: a -> StaticPtr (Get Foo)

instance StaticFoo String where
    staticFoo _ = static (Foo <$> (get :: Get String))

instance Binary Foo where
    put (Foo x) = do
        put $ staticKey $ staticFoo x
        put x

    get = do
        ptr <- get
        case unsafePerformIO (unsafeLookupStaticPtr ptr) of
            Just value -> deRefStaticPtr value :: Get Foo
            Nothing -> error "Binary Foo: unknown static pointer"
```

A full description of the solution can be found [on this blog post](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2017/09/existential-serialisation.html), and a complete snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/ndmitchell/a4f2edcedd2d4398efea4755b5d2408f).

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't seem to work without for each type manually adding a monomorphic getter that can be static-pointed to...

Comment: @leftaroundabout yep, that seems a pretty fundamental requirement of this approach. Still nicer than any of the other answers.

Comment: @abhiroop I've fleshed out your answer and turned it into the accepted answer, following the ideas you gave.

Comment: Thanks @NeilMitchell  The blog on this is very informative.

Answer (score 7):

You need some way that each `Binary` instance can register itself (just as in your `witness` version).  You can do this by bundling each instance declaration with an exported foreign symbol, where the symbol name is derived from the `TypeRep`.  Then when you want to deserialize you get the name from the `TypeRep` and look up that symbol dynamically (with `dlsym()` or something similar).  The value exported by the foreign export can, e.g., be the deserializer function.

It's crazy ugly, but it works.

Comment: Would you be so nice and explain your answer a little bit? If you could post any code snippet, that would be great! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you could do that, you would also be able to implement:

```
isValidRead :: TypeRep -> String -> Bool
```

This would be a function that changes its behavior due to someone defining a new type! Not very pure-ish.. I think (and hope) that one can't implement this in Haskell..

Comment: What does `isValidRead` do? Just because you can accurately serialise an existential, I don't think you can query the universe of types - since the existential captures a proof that the type existed before, so you can't observe a newly defined type.

Comment: @NeilMitchell: Perhaps I should had called it `isValidShow`. It tells whether the `String` argument is a possible result for `show` for the given type. If you use the `get` function of `Foo`'s `Binary` instance, it would indirectly tell whether its input is a valid result of `put`.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that slightly works in some situations (not enough for my purposes), but may be the best that can be done. You can add a `witness` function to witness any types that you have, and then the deserialisation can lookup in the witness table. The rough idea is (untested):

```
witnesses :: IORef [Foo]
witnesses = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef []

witness :: (Typeable a, Binary a) => a -> IO ()
witness x = modifyIORef (Foo x :)

instance Binary Foo where
    put (Foo x) = put (typeOf x) >> put x
    get = do
        ty <- get
        wits <- unsafePerformIO $ readIORef witnesses
        case [Foo x | Foo x <- wits, typeOf x == ty] of
            Foo x:_ -> fmap Foo $ get `asTypeOf` return x
            [] -> error $ "Could not find a witness for the type: " ++ show ty
```

The idea is that as you go through, you call `witness` on values of every type that you may plausibly encounter when deserialising. When you deserialise you search this list. The obvious problem is that if you fail to call `witness` before deserialisation you get a crash.

Comment: What do you need to import for the `Binary` instance of `TypeRep`?

Comment: Looks a little unsafe! </pun>

Comment: @yairchu: Nothing defines one, but there are enough functions to take it it apart and put it back together that you could write one (see `splitTyConApp` and `mkTyConApp`).